# Copy Object array values in textarea field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple object arrays in js and i want to insert them into `Textarea` elements accordingly

I have provided a code snipped below to see what im trying to do
and the problem im haven is when you click the `Paste` button it only inserts the last values of the array.
How do i make the button to copy paste all the array values into the textarea?

```js
var darkmode = {
    '1': {
    '--primary_button': '#000','--primary_button_font': '#ffffff'
    },
    '2': {
    '--primary_button': '#ffffff','--primary_button_font': '#000'
    }
};
    $('.tButton').on('click', function (event) {
      var val = $(this).attr('data-value'); //returns 1,2
        for (var i in darkmode[val]) {
          if (val === '1') {
              $('#scheme1 textarea').text([i] + ": " + darkmode[val][i]);

          }else if (val === '2') {
             $('#scheme2 textarea').text([i] + ": " + darkmode[val][i]);
          };
            
      };
    });
```

```html
<li id="scheme1">
  <textarea name="theme"></textarea>
  <button class="tButton " data-value="1">Paste</button>
</li>

<li id="scheme2">
  <textarea name="theme"></textarea>
  <button class="tButton " data-value="2">Paste</button>
</li>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The snipped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, what is happening here is that every time you insert a value into the textarea, it is getting replaced with the latest value inserted and hence you get to see the last value only.

Instead of using `text()`, use `append()` which actually `concats` the inserted values to the element instead of replacing it.

```js
var darkmode = {
    '1': {
    '--primary_button': '#000','--primary_button_font': '#ffffff'
    },
    '2': {
    '--primary_button': '#ffffff','--primary_button_font': '#000'
    }
};
    $('.tButton').on('click', function (event) {
      var val = $(this).attr('data-value'); //returns 1,2
        for (var i in darkmode[val]) {
          if (Number(val) === 1) {
              $('#scheme1 textarea').append([i] + ": " + darkmode[val][i]);

          }else if (Number(val) === 2) {
             $('#scheme2 textarea').append([i] + ": " + darkmode[val][i]);
          };
            
      };
    });
```

```html
<li id="scheme1">
  <textarea name="theme"></textarea>
  <button class="tButton " data-value="1">Paste</button>
</li>

<li id="scheme2">
  <textarea name="theme"></textarea>
  <button class="tButton " data-value="2">Paste</button>
</li>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var darkmode = {
  '1': {
    '--primary_button': '#000',
    '--primary_button_font': '#ffffff'
  },
  '2': {
    '--primary_button': '#ffffff',
    '--primary_button_font': '#000'
  },
  '3': {
    '--primary_button': '#fdfdfd',
    '--primary_button_font': '#fff'
  }
};
$('.tButton').on('click', function(event) {
  var getClickedElement = event.target.getAttribute('data-value')
  var val = $(this).attr('data-value');
  for (var i in darkmode[val]) {
    if (Number(val) == getClickedElement) {
      $('#scheme' + getClickedElement + ' textarea ').append([i] + ": " + darkmode[val][i]);
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<li id="scheme1">
  <textarea name="theme"></textarea>
  <button class="tButton " data-value="1">Paste</button>
</li>

<li id="scheme2">
  <textarea name="theme"></textarea>
  <button class="tButton " data-value="2">Paste</button>
</li>
<li id="scheme3">
  <textarea name="theme"></textarea>
  <button class="tButton " data-value="3">Paste</button>
</li>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Note:- This will be the dynamic solution for multiple values...